# Conectar servidor em rede local pelo hostname

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando conectar a um servidor de rede local usando o *hostname* (não dá pra usar IP porque a rede do cliente não permite colocar ip fixo e o equipamento não tem reserva de IP por MAC).

Então, estou tentando fazer isto desde uma aplicação Android, até o momento consegui buscar o IP a partir do *hostname* porém como existe mais de uma placa de rede na máquina, só está me retornando um dos IPs.

O código que está me retornando um IP é o seguinte: (em asyncTask)

```
ArrayList <String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

try
{
    InetAddress ipaddress = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
    lista.add(ipaddress.getHostAddress());
}
catch (UnknownHostException e)
{
    lista.add("Ip não encontrado para o hostname: "+ hostname);
}

return  lista;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encontrei no stack em inglês o seguinte código.

```
try {
Log.d("ReverseDNS", "Reverse DNS for 8.8.8.8 is: " + InetAddress.getByName("8.8.8.8").getHostName());
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
 Log.e("ReverseDNS", "Oh no, 8.8.8.8 has no reverse DNS record!");
}
```

Ele usa um DNS Reverse Lookup, essa operação pode demorar um pouco, então rode em uma tarefa assíncrona.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521844/how-to-resolve-network-host-names-from-ip-address) da pergunta em inglês.